# how to get data from java server to javascript by using socket io and nodejs?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am dealing with a sort of gps tracking system. i have a map and i need to update the current position of the vehicle. i need to use socket io for real time visualization. i checked out nodejs tutorials but could not derive a solution. i have a server written in java and i want to send updates to my map written in javascript. so how can i receive data from my java server by using socket io and/or nodejs?`var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(????)` what should i add to these code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebSockets (HTML5). Install the websocket package to the folder where your node.js server is running:

```
npm install websocket
```

Here a [link](http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial) to a good tutorial about websockets and node.js.